# How to hide file extensions for all files, including overwriting the files individual setting?

Tags: macos, finder

Client wants to hide file name extensions to avoid removing them by mistake when renaming files. I used Finder preferences to uncheck the "Show all filename extensions" option.

This only hid a extensions from some files. Most files in various locations still show the extension, including in newly downloaded files.

When right clicking on the files and going to "Show Info", I can see each file has this checked (including newly downloaded files).

Is there a way to force all files to not show the file extension?

Answer (score 2):

We use a tool to drag and drop process files and remove that metadata.

- https://www.publicspace.net/ABetterFinderAttributes/index.html

Test it and then make a droplet if you continue to get specific files with setting you don’t like.

[image: change file extension with a tool]

Comment: I will take a look, thanks. Although shouldn't new files not have this meta data? I mean files not even created on Mac. Mainly PDF's coming from their scanner, but any document emailed from a Windows PC will also have the extension showing.

Comment: It may depend which application introduces the file locally @user2924019 - I can’t reproduce the case where you’re seeing these widely tbh. Have you restarted after electing the new default state for files?

Comment: Outlook scan to email being saved as a PDF. Honestly, I've never seen this on any other Mac.

Comment: If you open a command line shell and type file then drag one of these PDF into the terminal window  - I wonder if these are applications and not pdf…

Comment: 100% PDF's, Been scanning to email for years from that same all-in-one. Never had a scanner scan to an application file. The same issue happens with .docx, .xlsx files emailed from Windows PC's too. I suspect there's some missing updates on the clients Mac, so I will ask them to ensure it's been fully updated. Thanks for your suggestions.